# Can't make a simple call to a web-service with NuSoap

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, nusoap

This is my very first time working with web-services and NuSoap (and SOAP overall). What I'm trying to do is a very simple CALL function using NuSoap, and as simple as it looks, I just can't make it work.

This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once('nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');

$url = "http://server10logic.com/WSAmib-0.1/services/comprobanteOperacion?wsdl";


try
{
    $client = new nusoap_client($url);
    $result = $client->call('listComprobanteOperacion');

}
catch (SoapFault $e)
{
    echo 'Error0'.$e->getMessage() . "\n";
}

echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
?>
```

The result of that code can be seen here:

http://dev.etic.com.mx/bmv/test.php

ANY help will be greatly welcome. If you need more information just let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

While creating the client, add a second `boolean` parameter, `true`, which tells the library that you are working with a WSDL file.

`$client = new nusoap_client($url, true);`